# Error setting up a field to hold an array of checkbox choices

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm upgrading from Symfony 1.4 to Symfony 2.6.4 and can't figure out how to set up a form field to hold a set of choices (seems simple enough) from a stored entity.  I get an error when I go to create my schema.

Code:

```
<?php 

namespace PlantBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class PlantForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('propagationMethod', 'entity', array(
            'class'         =>  'PlantBundle:PropagationMethod',
            'property'      =>  'name',
            'expanded'      =>  true,
            'multiple'      =>  true,
            'required'      =>  false,
            'label'         =>  'Propagation Methods',
            'attr'          =>  array(
                'class' =>  'checkboxes'
        )));
    }
}


<?php

namespace PlantBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PlantBundle\Entity\Repository\PlantRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="plant")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Plant
{   
# ...

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     */
    protected $propagationMethodIds;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PlantBundle\Entity\PropagationMethod")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="propagationMethodIds", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $propagationMethod;    

# ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->propagationMethod = new ArrayCollection();
    }

# ...   
}
```

Error message when generating schema:

[PDOException]
   SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1170 BLOB/TEXT column 'propagationMethodIds' 
  used in key specification without a key length

I've tried adding a length=255 to the field but still get the error.  From the research I've done troubleshooting the problem, it seems that the field is being indexed, and since it is a blob it needs the length specified.  But the field is an array of ids from a related table.  Confused :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and experimentation I found a solution that works.  Since the documentation is lacking, and there weren't any answers to the question, I do not know if this is the correct or best way to achieve the desired outcome, but as I mentioned, it works.  I'm providing the solution here in hopes that it helps others stuck on the issue.

```
<?php 

//  Correct.  No changes needed.

namespace PlantBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class PlantForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {

        $builder->add('propagationMethod', 'entity', array(
            'class'         =>  'PlantBundle:PropagationMethod',
            'property'      =>  'name',
            'expanded'      =>  true,
            'multiple'      =>  true,
            'required'      =>  false,
            'label'         =>  'Propagation Methods',
            'attr'          =>  array(
                'class' =>  'checkboxes'
        )));
    }
}


<?php

namespace PlantBundle\Entity;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;


/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="PlantBundle\Entity\Repository\PlantRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="plant")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Plant
{   
# ...

/*
 *    This column is not needed at all. It creates all kinds of problems by keeping it. Delete:
 *
 *    /**
 *     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
 *     */
 *    protected $propagationMethodIds;
 *
 */ 

 //   Add the column type above to the ORM mapping below.  Also remove the name association on the JoinColumn.

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="array", nullable=true)
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="PlantBundle\Entity\PropagationMethod")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $propagationMethod;    

//    Correct.  No changes:     

# ...
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->propagationMethod = new ArrayCollection();
    }

# ...   
}

/*
 *  This is how I displayed the stored array data:
 *
*/


// show.html.twig

{% extends 'PlantBundle::layout.html.twig' %}
{% block stylesheets %}
    {{ parent() }} <link href="{{ asset('bundles/~/plant.css') }}" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
{% endblock %}
{% block title %}Plant Details{% endblock%}
{% block body %}
    {% for method in plant.propagationMethod %}{{ method.name }} {% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```